# AngularJS - ng-repeat Showing single records Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with AngularJS. I am getting strange behavior from `ng-repeat`. I have a controller which returns me the data to `ng-repeat` such as:

```
.....
//My other JS Functions
.....
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
        controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
            var data = [
                //data in JSON form
            ];

            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 5           // count per page
            }, {
                total:data.length,
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    var slicedData = data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    alert(slicedData.length);
                    console.log(slicedData);
                    $defer.resolve(slicedData);
                }
            });
        })
```

So, now one thing to note here that I am getting expected data after slicing it that I am passing to:

```
$defer.resolve(slicedData);
```

So, no issue seems here as it passes desired data.
Now, I have `ng-repeat` where I show data in form of tables such as:

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table ng-table-responsive">            

            <tr ng-repeat="d in $data">

                <td data-title="Name">
                    {{d.id}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="length">{{$data.length}}</td>
                <td data-title="Age">
                    {{d.ciscoID}}
                </td>
            </tr>
 </table>
```

So, here I am getting accurate length that is 5. But the number of records(rows) shown are 25(5*5) that each row is shown five times. Similarly, if I set the count to 10, then each record will be shown ten times.

I am unable to understand this scenario as

```
<td data-title="length">{{$data.length}}</td>
```

gives me the correct length then it should iterate correctly too.

P.S. My `getData()` method in the controller is called twice don't know why?

Any help/guidance regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'd consider making a jsFiddle which describes your issue.

Comment: Reason behind de-voting this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Issue was fixed just by replacing the 'JS' and 'CSS' files with the latest ones.